# Why does is not entering to the right url?

Tags: django, url, django-views

I am making a project in school, making a site.
when i click on nvbar its enter to the right URL but when i enter to another category its doesn't work.

for example:
if i enter to login:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
if i enter to register after login:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/register
and i need it to enter:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/register

Code:

```
URLS:
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_screen_view, name="home"),
    path('register/', registration_view, name="register"),
    path('logout/', logout_view, name="logout"),
    path('login/', login_view, name="login"),
    path('account/', account_view, name="account"),
    path('Sourcesofknowledge/', Sourcesofknowledge_view, name="Sourcesofknowledge"),
    path('customersatisfactionsurvey/', customersatisfactionsurvey_view, name="customersatisfactionsurvey"),
    ]
nvbar:
<div class="w3-top">
    <div class="w3-bar w3-black w3-card w3-left-align w3-large">
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right w3-padding-large w3-hover-white w3-large w3-red" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Hello, {{request.user.username}}</p>
        <a href="" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-white">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Medicinal stock</a>
        <a href="Sourcesofknowledge" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Sources of knowledge</a>
        <a href="customersatisfactionsurvey" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Satisfaction Survey</a>
        <a href="logout" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Logout</a>
        <a href="account" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">account</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-white">Home</a>
        <a href="login" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Login</a>
        <a href="register" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Registry</a>
        <a href="Sourcesofknowledge" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Sources of knowledge</a>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to say more about what isn't working. Do you see an error message? If so, what is it? It is not producing the expected output? If not, what output do you see and what output do you expect?

Comment: Can you also improve the grammar in the question title?  As written it makes no sense and I'm not sure what you were intending, so I can't fix it for you.

Comment: `href="/register"`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you can use `{% url ... %}` learn more here 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url

```
<div class="w3-top">
    <div class="w3-bar w3-black w3-card w3-left-align w3-large">
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right w3-padding-large w3-hover-white w3-large w3-red" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Hello, {{request.user.username}}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-white">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Medicinal stock</a>
        <a href="{% url 'Sourcesofknowledge' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Sources of knowledge</a>
        <a href="{% url 'customersatisfactionsurvey' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Satisfaction Survey</a>
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Logout</a>
        <a href="{% url 'account' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">account</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-white">Home</a>
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Login</a>
        <a href="{% url 'register' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Registry</a>
        <a href="{% url 'Sourcesofknowledge' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Sources of knowledge</a>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```